# How can I change blogger html code to increase the speed of my website?

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I am wondering what I can do to increase the page loading speed of my website hosted on blogger. I have some experience with html but not enough to know how to fix performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control their speed, but you can control yours. It the same as any website, optimize images, keep amount of resources to the most comfortable minimum, etc.

Did you do some reaserch? `speed up blogspot` is giving me PLENTY of results on Google (to the point I'm actually doubting wether to keep this post):

- http://weblogs.about.com/od/searchengineoptimization/tp/10-Ways-To-Speed-Up-Blog-Page-Load-Speed-And-Increase-Search-Traffic.htm
- https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/42394?hl=en
- http://www.codeitpretty.com/2013/09/why-is-my-blogger-blog-so-slow.html